# SQL case statement with multiple IDS showing repeated values

Tags: sql, case

I am aware that the case statement below selects the first true condition:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN 1/1 = 1 THEN 'Case 1'
      WHEN 2/2 = 1 THEN 'Case 2'
   END;
```

I have a problem in which there is a single user that appears to have both  Case 1 and case 2 in multiple rows.

The image below shows user id  aaaa appearing more than once for each case evaluation. I am lookin for a way to have my sql produce only one outcome for user aaaa even if user aaaa appears 100 times in the table. I want it to show the first true outcome for that user .

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmCBs.png)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hm2r.png)

Comment: *The image below* - there is no image. However don't fix that, edit your question and add sample data and expected results as *text*.

Comment: Edited to add the expected result and the outcome. Data is classified

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CASE 
      WHEN 1/1 = 1 THEN 'Case 1'
      WHEN 2/0 = 1 THEN 'Case 2'
   END as OutCome,
UserId
FROM mytable
```

OR

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN 1/1 = 1 THEN 'Case 1'
      WHEN 2/0 = 1 THEN 'Case 2'
   END as OutCome,
UserId
FROM mytable
GROUP BY OutCome, UserId
```

Comment: That is pretty simple. I have edited the question to reflect what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Yemisi why are you showing the first "aaaa" if you dont want duplicated?

Comment: That was a mistake on my part . I have edited it

Comment: If that is the expected result, why my answer don't help you?

Comment: I am not getting distinct user ids with your logic

Comment: @Yemisi you should it with the last query.